ASP.NET MVC data annotations: initial data is null, but required input value on submit form
I have the situation that is the Notes column inside of the table is NULL. This data is imported automatically.
I have page where user open to edit that record including the Notes field, but the Notes field is required value when user submits the form. I know the validation for Notes field can be down at the client-side using Javascript, but I like validate using ASP.NET MVC data annotations if possible.
Here is the model class (simplified):
public class DetailModel
{
    // Some other properties here....
    public string? Notes { get; set; }
}

From the controller, it calls the method shown here below and the edit page works fine:
public async Task<ActionResult?> Detail(string? id)
{
   DetailModel? Detail = await _StoredProcedures.GetDetail(id);
   return View(Detail);
}


public async Task<DetailModel?> GetDetail(string? id)
{
    List<DetailModel> Info = await _context.Database.SqlQuery<DetailModel>($@"EXECUTE [dbo].[p_DetailView] @Method = 'Info', @RecID = {id}").ToListAsync();
    return Info.FirstOrDefault();
}

Now if I try to validate using the data annotations as shown here, it will break:
public class DetailModel
{
    // Some other properties here....
        
    [Required]
    public string? Notes { get; set; }
}

Error message:

SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.ThrowIfNull()
InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while reading a database value for property 'DetailModel.Notes'. The expected type was 'System.String' but the actual value was null.

Is there a way to overcome this? Given the initial data is NULL, but enforce on the form submit to require value using data annotations?

Create another model class that is used for the form submit, with applying the [Required] attribute to the Notes property. While your model class that is used to map/fetch data from the database shouldn't use the Required attribute as the column is nullable.

I am new to MVC stuff and tried to follow, but couldn't get it to work.  I copied the DetailModel (not Required for Notes) to the new DetailViewModel, then include Required for Notes in that new DetailViewModell. Afterthat, I changed the view to @model DetailViewModel and change controller action to DetailViewModel? Detail = await _StoredProcedures.GetDetail(id);, but it won't work because the _context.Database.SqlQuery<DetailModel> was a different model.   Please advise how can I have the view with different model than the SqlQuery<DetailModel> with an example if possible.

You may want to have a mapper, a DTO and a ViewModel.
In this way your DTO, which you use to exchange data with database, may be:
public class DetailDto
{
    public string? Notes { get; set; }
}

Your View Model, which you use for your form, may be:
public class DetailModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}

Then you can do mapping from one shape to another when you need:
DetailDto dto = await _StoredProcedures.GetDetail(id);
DetailModel detailModel = DtoMapper.Map(dto);

You can start with simple static mapper and later consider more advanced technics:
public static class DtoMapper
{
    public static DetailModel Map(DetailDto dto)
    {
        return new DetailModel
        {
             Notes = dto.Notes;
        };
    }
    
    public static DetailDto Map(DetailModel model)
    {
        return new DetailDto
        {
            Notes = model.Notes;
        };
    }    
}

With this, when you receive DetailModel from the form you can use the power of data annotations along with the aforementioned if (ModelState.IsValid). If the data passes the validation you can map it back from DetailModel to DetailDto, and save to database.

It works. Thank you so much for the sample code which helped a lot.

So, the error message indicates that it's coming from the database as null, and you're trying to populate a model that has the required attribute set on that column.
Using the [Required] attribute does not support a nullable column in the database, because when the model is built and populated, it obviously has nothing to fill that with.
This is a circumstance, where you can either check the required fields using annotations at the controller level, or you can use a DTO to move the data from your client to your server - and validate the posted data to the DTO and then map it into your database model.
Using a DTO is quite common, and considered good practice because it keeps the exact shape of your database model obscured from the client.  It does break the DRY principle a bit, but it's a trade off.
You also didn't show where you post that model back with all the fields filled up, are you sure that your Notes column isn't ending up null when you post it back?

Thanks for the suggestion. I am new to MVC and a little lost if your suggestion.  In the controller, the [HttpPost] action request just has `if (ModelState.IsValid)'.  Can you please give a sample code for "check the required fields using annotations at the controller level" and DTO (I have no idea what it is).  much appreciated!
